# How to make sure Swing UI is actually displayed on screen?

Tags: java, swing

When I click on button another JFrame class is getting opened. The JFrame will be visible on the screen after 2 seconds but the isVisible returns true before that. I want to start timer when the JFrame actually getting displayed on the screen. How can I achieve this ? I tried to used isShowing() and isDisplayable() but it's not giving expected result.

Comment: 2s seems long to display a JFrame, probably making it look unresponsive. Maybe you should change the way to initialize your frame and it's content instead of waiting for it to show

Comment: You'll have to attach some listener to your JFrame which will be triggered when your JFrame is displayed. Like [WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent))

Comment: I agree with @jhamon. I hope you're not trying to work around a potential design flaw.

Comment: can you explain what take this processing time?

Comment: @jhamon - Delay will be only at first time, maybe UI is taking long time to initialize.

Comment: You have a logic problem. The frame should be visible in a few ms. Post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MainApp {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main");
    JButton button = new JButton("Toggle auxiliary");
    JFrame auxFrame = new JFrame("Auxiliary");

    public MainApp() {
        button.addActionListener(evt -> {
            // Delay displaying for 2 seconds
            Timer timer = new Timer(2000, event -> {
                auxFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                auxFrame.setSize(320, 240);
                auxFrame.setVisible(true);
            });
            timer.start();
            auxFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                    // Stop timer after the auxiliary frame is displayed
                    timer.stop();
                }
            });

        });

        frame.add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(320, 240);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(MainApp::new);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```java
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()
```

Example:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class Main extends JFrame {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(
        () -> {
          Main main = new Main();
          main.setVisible(true);
          main.setSize(600, 800);
          main.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          System.out.println("UI Loaded");
        });
    System.out.println("everything else will be executed after UI is loaded");
  }
}
```

Console output:

```
UI Loaded
everything else will be executed after UI is loaded
```